# Is there a way to concat C# anonymous types?

Tags: c#, types, anonymous

For example

```
var hello = new { Hello = "Hello" };
var world = new { World = "World" };
var helloWorld = hello + world;
Console.WriteLine(helloWorld.ToString());
//outputs {Hello = Hello, World = World}
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Big picture..., What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm using ASP.Net MVC and have found it very easy to present anonymous objects in Json format using somethings like this:

var posts = postService.GetPersonalPosts(1, 10, UserId);
return Json(posts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

and was wondering if there was a way to easily combine the properties from two anonymous types into one.

Answer (score 8):

No. hello and world objects are objects of different classes.

The only way to merge these classes is to use dynamic type generation ([Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx)). Here is example of such concatenation: http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2008/02/12/extend-anonymous-types-using.aspx

Quote from mentioned article:

> The process works like this: First use
>   System.ComponentModel.GetProperties to
>   get a PropertyDescriptorCollection
>   from the anonymous type. Fire up
>   Reflection.Emit to create a new
>   dynamic assembly and use TypeBuilder
>   to create a new type which is a
>   composite of all the properties
>   involved. Then cache the new type for
>   reuse so you don't have to take the
>   hit of building the new type every
>   time you need it.

Comment: I would venture that if you need to do all this for this kind of thing, you're using the anonymous types wrong.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with Lasse. While it might be an interesting workaround, its not a reasonable solution. Thanks for letting me know its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

No - They are different types and the `+` operator on both those types is undefined.

As a side note: I don't think you mean `concatenate`. In C#, concatenate is something you do to two or more `IEnumeration`s that puts them "end to end". For instance, the Linq method `Concat()` or `String.Concat()` (strings are "collections" of char). What you describe in your question is more like a join or multiple-inheritance between two unrelated types. I can't think of anything similar to that in C#, besides using autonomous types as in the alternative below:

```
var hello = new { Hello = "Hello" };
var world = new { World = "World" };
var helloWorld = new { hello, world };
Console.WriteLine(helloWorld.ToString());
//outputs { hello = { Hello = Hello }, world = { World = World } }
```

Comment: Concatenation was the best word I could find to describe the merging of two anonymous types; each with its own "collections" of members.

Answer (score 1):

```
var helloWorld = new { Hello = hello.Hello, World = world.World };
```

You can write a method that does this automatically using reflection API.   That's as close to this as I see possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hello = new { Hello = "Hello" };
var world = new { World = "World" };
var z = new { x = hello, y = world };
```

pass it right to the json serializer and viola.